# Android, listviews and activities architecture

Tags: android

I am new to Android and here I have a question about architecture:

I have an Activity that displays a ListView of social networks classes, each social network class is a regular class (not Activity) that implements an interface that has a login method. So when I tap on one social network from the ListView I call the login method of the network selected, and that method should call an activity that displays a webview with the login site of that network to get an Oauth token, when the user logs and authorize the app, the webview needs to be closed and the Item of the ListView should show that the user is now logged for the network selected.

So my questions are:
A regular class (not Activity) can call an Activity to open a webview? How? 
And then, how can that class listen to the result of the Activity and send that response to the Activity that displays the ListView in order to update it?
Is that architecture ok? I think that there should be a better and more elegant way, no?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you is to start the `Activity` that displays the `WebView` from within the `ListView` `Activity`. You can start the WebView Activity with `startActivityForResult()` method and listen for the result in `onActivityResult()`.

You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) page to see how you can do it.

If you still want to start an activity from a non `Activity Class`, then you have to make a `Application Context Provider` and start the activity using the application context. Note that you have to set the NEW_TASK flag when you start an activity from a non Activity Class. The problem is that I don't think you can get the onActivityResult() method called if you start the activity in this way.

Comment: Hi @Cata, thanks for your answer. If I do it in the first way, I have to do the implementation of each social network on that ListView Activity, losing the idea of having a class of each social network that handles the login of it, or I can still do that?

Comment: I misclicked before I could post the complete answer :p

Comment: You still can do your login implementations in the WbView activity that you start.. just start the corresponding activity of the list item pressed

Answer (score 0):

A [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) inherits from View, so it needs to be in the layout structure of an Activity. You'll need to build and Activity for handling the web login if that's your desire.

You can use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to indicate that you want a result from an Activity that is being launched and then later use [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to return result.

Answer (score 0):

In order for something to call an activity it needs a context. If you need an class that is not an activity, but part of an activity, to have that authority, you need to pass a context into that class. Be warned, if that class somehow remains post-activity in any way, you can leak the context.